# After upgrade to 13.04, Screen is flipped - text is left-to-right but upside down

Tags: upgrade, 13.04

I upgraded to 13.04 last night.  When I rebooted and logged in, this is what I saw.

[image: reversed text on screen]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Type `gnome-control-center display` into the terminal. Then click on rotation and change it to "Normal" or "180 Degrees" which ever is not the current setting. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well . . . I use arandr to set up a dual monitor system, and it has an 'invert' setting. Maybe worth a try.

[image]

Comment: A quick search lead me to this:

http://blog.manoharbhattarai.com.np/2010/05/06/how-to-rotate-or-flip-your-ubuntu-desktop-upside-down/